# Python: How to store iteration results to multiple lists or dataframe columns?

Tags: python, loops

I am iterating over multiple text files in a directory and looking to store the results (finalwords) for each text file into a separate list. When I run the following, only the result for the last text file in the directory appears in each column in the dataframe. How do I get the list to store the iteration results for each individual text file without overwriting previous iterations, so the each column in df1 displays the contents (finalwords) for each individual text file?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import os
import glob
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

mydirectory = '~/Documents/Textfiles'

datasentence = [] 

for filename in os.listdir(mydirectory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(infile, "r") as input_file:
            sentences = sent_tokenize(input_file.read())
            tokens = [w.lower() for w in sentences]
            table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
            stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
            finalwords = [w for w in stripped if not w in stop_words]
            datasentence.append(finalwords)  

df1=pd.DataFrame(datasentence).T
display(df1.head())
```

Comment: I don't understand your code in the 2nd last line. What is lists in df1=pd.DataFrame(lists).T? shouldn't it be datasentence?

Comment: Can you print datascentence and write if it contains the values as expected?

Comment: It just contains the string of words (finalwords) from that last text file in the directory and not for the previous text files.

Comment: Ok good. Now check if its a reference error. Try to append a copy of your list to the data sentence list. finalwords.copy(). If not check your list comprehension. Edit: SammyG commented below that your code returns all text. Meaning that probably your list comprehensions in combination with your files are causing the missing files/ values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I can help but to use display don't you need to run IPython.display import display and the same for string (i.e import string)?

you haven't defined lists from which the dataframe is generated......

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import os
import glob
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

mydirectory = 'your path'

datasentence = [] 
os.chdir(mydirectory)
for filename in os.listdir(mydirectory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
            sentences = sent_tokenize(input_file.read())
            tokens = [w.lower() for w in sentences]
            table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
            stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
            finalwords = [w for w in stripped if not w in stop_words]
            datasentence.append(finalwords)  

df1=pd.DataFrame(datasentence).T

display(df1.head())
```

Comment: I have generated 4 random text files and you code returns the text from each file

Comment: I have just pasted your code into a new notebook and was able to get the result - not sure why it wasn't working before. Thank you!

Comment: following your comments, and if it makes you feel better - me neither